# While loop doesn't stop when looping through dates

Tags: python, loops, pandas

Why does this while loop never stop?

```
t = pd.to_datetime('2016.03.04')
T = pd.to_datetime('2019.09.04')
dates = T

while dates > t:

    dates = T- pd.DateOffset(years=1)
    print(dates)
```

Please help

Comment: because your condition is always True ;)

Comment: change it to: `dates -= pd.DateOffset(years=1)`

Comment: As a piece of general advice, I would recommend against creating variables that differ only in case (`t` and `T`) here, as it will be quite confusing to readers (and *readability counts*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not summing the offsets.

Change this line:

```
dates = T - pd.DateOffset(years=1)
```

to this:

```
dates -= pd.DateOffset(years=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to do something like this instead of looping:

```
dates =  pd.date_range('2016.03.04',periods=4,freq=pd.DateOffset(years=1))
print(dates)
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-03-04', '2017-03-04', '2018-03-04', '2019-03-04'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='<DateOffset: kwds={'years': 1}>')
```